# Easy Linux photo editing software

Tags: linux, photography, image-editor, image

Please recommend an easy Linux photo edit software for a person who is new in Linux. She is a real estate worker and takes photos of interiors. She has to crop them, rotate, and shrink to 1000 KB or less each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gthumb) is a simple image viewer that can also do simple editing like rotation, cropping, resizing and format/compression change.

For anything more advanced I would recommend [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/). It is maybe overkill for simply cropping a photo, but it's free, so hey, why not use it?

Answer (score 1):

**[Pinta](https://www.pinta-project.com/)** ships with most Linux distributions, some (like Linux Mint) having installed it by default. It's not as heavy as GIMP, and looks rather suited to beginners. You can check its [Documentation](https://www.pinta-project.com/howto) to see what features are covered – all mentioned by you should be there ("shrink" can be achieved by resizing and also by compression when saving/exporting the image). To give you some visuals, here's a screenshot taken from their homepage:

[image]
<sup>*Pinta* (source: [Pinta](https://www.pinta-project.com/); click/tap image for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

for fast **editing** and **viewing** i use [Shotwell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell)

a **very light** software like photo viewers, but you can easily `crop`, `rotate`, `adjust`, ...

---

### Like a photo viewers

you can use it **like a photo viewers**:

[image]

---

### Like a photo browsers

or you can use it **like a file browser** and browse in your photos:

[image]